# How to allow Tornado Web Server serve only local requests (from Django)?

Tags: django, tornado

I am using Django for main project + Tornado for some async staff.

So, some Django apps requests Tornado via http.

And Tornado server is accessible by mywebsite.com:8888 in browser.

I want to throw 403 error or disable it at all for users if possible, and make it work only for local request from Django.

How can I do it? Can nginx help me? Or there is some cool feature in Tornado? Or some unix staff?

Big thx for advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Django and Tornado are running on the same server, you can bind Tornado to 127.0.0.1 by call [.listen()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.listen) with appropriate parameter:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    application.listen(8888, address='127.0.0.1')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```